# python .rstrip() does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a text file, there is a specific line:

```
"*** Golden[0] , silver[0] ***",,,,,,,,,
```

I use

```
    with open(filename.split('.')[0] + '_split.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith('"***'):
                titles.extend( [line.rstrip(','), str(len(titles))] )
            else:
                for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', line):
                    pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

    df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values(), columns = titles)
```

to strip all the commas, but it does not work, it remains the same.
I was expecting to have:

```
"*** Golden[0]  silver[0] ***"
```

Anyone knows how I should fix it?

Comment: With python3 (3.8), this is what you get. What's the output you currently have?

Comment: It's impossible to tell based on your just description. My guess is that you think that strings are mutable while they aren't. Are you doing `line = line.rstrip(',')` or just `line.rstrip()`?

Comment: Off topic. but the `str(len(titles))` part, probably isn't doing what you think it is either. It's counting the previous length of `titles`.

Answer (score 3):

You should check what `rstrip(',')` does. It strips the `,` characters from the string starting from the right until a character not equal to `,` is met. When the quote `"` is seen, stripping stops.

Most likely you wanted to use `replace` function to remove all commas with  `line.replace(',', '')`

```
if line.startswith('"***'):
    titles.extend( [line.replace(',', ''), str(len(titles))] )
```